# Maximal determinant of a $\{1,−1\}$ matrix of size $n$ is $2^{n−1}$ times the maximal determinant of a $ \{0,1\}$ matrix of size $n−1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, determinant

Maximal determinant of a $\{1,−1\}$ matrix of size $n$ is $2^{n−1}$ times the maximal determinant of a $ \{0,1\}$  matrix of size $n−1$. How to prove this result?  (I found this statement while reading Hadamard's Maximal Determinant problem)

Can we prove it by applying induction?

Any hint or remark towards any other proof is highly appreciated.

Comment: See [Connection of the maximal determinant problems for {1, −1} and {0, 1} matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem#Connection_of_the_maximal_determinant_problems_for_.7B1.2C.C2.A0.E2.88.921.7D_and_.7B0.2C.C2.A01.7D_matrices) in the Wikipedia article on Hadamard's maximal determinant problem.